# How to calculate the maximum output rate of this DAC?

Tags: spi, dac

Regarding [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8555.pdf?ts=1664472796044) DAC, if it is controlled by SPI how can we calculate the output speed? If I use max 50 MHz clock freq. for a single channel how fast the output would be? This must be something to do with number of SPI rising edges but I'm no expert and would love to know how it is estimated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what specs you require.

Datasheet says it can reach update rates of 1 MSPS for small changes. It also says it has excellent performance up to 10 kHz.

But since it has up to 50 MHz clock, and needs 24 bits per command, so in practice it can be approximately reach 2 million commands per second, which means approximately 1 MSPS per channel given above.

Comment: Thank you. But why 2 million command per second does not correspond to 2 MSPS but 1 MSPS?

Comment: It does if you limit to 1 channel or update both channels with same data. But if you need to update each channel separately then you must send two commands.